# Node.JS Overwrite module export value

Tags: node.js

How can I overwrite a module export value?
Currently I have this:

temp.js

```
let lastrsss = '';


module.exports = {

    lastrsss


};
```

I try overwrite the value with this:

```
const temprss = require('../../temp'); 
temprss.lastrsss = "https://something.com";
```

It works, but same time it doesn't. I think it saves in memory or I don't know. It doesn't save in temp.js. How can I do that it will save in temp.js?

Comment: It won't; it's local to `temp.js`, that's the point of modules. You could create a function in `temp` used to set an internal variable, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple ways to handle this. A nice clean one is to define a getter and setter:

*temp.js*

```
lastrsss = "hello"

module.exports = {
    get lastrsss() {
        return lastrsss
    },
    set lastrsss(val){
        lastrsss = val
    }
}
```

Now you can use them just like regular properties:

```
let tempres = require('./test2.js')

console.log(tempres.lastrsss)  // hello
tempres.lastrsss = "goodbye"
console.log(tempres.lastrsss)  // goodbye
```

Answer (score 0):

Export a function to create and set a value in the lastrsss.

Try something like this:

```
function setLastrsss(value) {
    let lastrsss = value;
    return lastrsss;
}

module.exports = {
   setLastrsss;
}
```